# Правильна ли постановка зн. препинания при однородных членах?

Tags: пунктуация

У меня в квартире разостланы разнообразные ковры - зеленый, синий, желтый.

Правильна ли постановка знаков препинания?

Answer (score 1):

Предложение с обобщающим словом перед однородным рядом определений. Возможны **два варианта** оформления:

*У меня в квартире разостланы ковры разного цвета: **зеленый, синий, желтый.*** Пояснительное значение.

*У меня в квартире разостланы ковры разных цветов **— зеленый, синий, желтый**.* Присоединительное значение.

Примечание. Разнообразные ковры — это такие ковры, которые различаются не только по цвету.